# Drop a named column if and only if all values are NA

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr, purrr

I am developing a package and I am getting trouble when I desire to drop a named all-NA column without dropping other columns that are also all-NA.

Here is an example of a data frame. In this example we have two all-NA columns and this is expected and correct.

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <- tribble(
  ~a,       ~b,    ~c,         ~d, ~AR, ~BR,
  1L, "animal", "dog",         NA,  NA,  NA,
  2L, "animal", "cat",         NA,  NA,  NA,
  3L, "animal", "rat",         NA,  NA,  NA,
  4L,  "plant", "oak", "carvalho",  NA,  NA
) %>% 
  mutate_if(is.logical, as.character)

df
#> # A tibble: 4 x 6
#>       a b      c     d        AR    BR   
#>   <int> <chr>  <chr> <chr>    <chr> <chr>
#> 1     1 animal dog   <NA>     <NA>  <NA> 
#> 2     2 animal cat   <NA>     <NA>  <NA> 
#> 3     3 animal rat   <NA>     <NA>  <NA> 
#> 4     4 plant  oak   carvalho <NA>  <NA>
```

<sup>Created on 2020-02-06 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

However, suppose that I filter the column `b` to show only animals. In that case we would have three all-NA columns: `d`, `AR` and `BR`.

```r
df %>% 
  filter(b == "animal")

df
#> # A tibble: 3 x 6
#>       a b      c     d     AR    BR   
#>   <int> <chr>  <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>
#> 1     1 animal dog   <NA>  <NA>  <NA> 
#> 2     2 animal cat   <NA>  <NA>  <NA> 
#> 3     3 animal rat   <NA>  <NA>  <NA>
```

<sup>Created on 2020-02-06 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

In the function I am developing, I want that in the case above, when `d` is all-NA, it is dropped but any other all-NA columns is not dropped. So, just a `select(-d)` doesn't work because it would totally remove the column `d`, even if it had content.

I already tried `tidyr::drop_na`, `purrr::discard` and `dplyr::select_if` - in conjunction with `all(is.na())` but without success dropping only the column `d`. I am in search of a way that preferably works with pipes. The only way I got to do this is not pipe friendly: `if(all(is.na(df$d))) df$d <- NULL`

EDIT:

The result I am expecting is a function that when I run it in the original df, it would return the exact same df as the original one:

```r
df
#> # A tibble: 4 x 6
#>       a b      c     d        AR    BR   
#>   <int> <chr>  <chr> <chr>    <chr> <chr>
#> 1     1 animal dog   <NA>     <NA>  <NA> 
#> 2     2 animal cat   <NA>     <NA>  <NA> 
#> 3     3 animal rat   <NA>     <NA>  <NA> 
#> 4     4 plant  oak   carvalho <NA>  <NA>
```

But in the case column `d` is all-NA, I am expecting the following in return:

```r
df
#> # A tibble: 3 x 5
#>       a b      c     AR    BR   
#>   <int> <chr>  <chr> <chr> <chr>
#> 1     1 animal dog   <NA>  <NA> 
#> 2     2 animal cat   <NA>  <NA> 
#> 3     3 animal rat   <NA>  <NA>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `select_if()` and test the conditions with `%in%` (in the case of multiple vars) for the column names and `colSums()` counting non-na values.

```
df %>%
  filter(b == 'animal') %>%
  select_if(!names(.) %in% "d" | colSums(!is.na(.)) > 0)

# A tibble: 3 x 5
      a b      c     AR    BR   
  <int> <chr>  <chr> <chr> <chr>
1     1 animal dog   NA    NA   
2     2 animal cat   NA    NA   
3     3 animal rat   NA    NA  


df %>%
  select_if(!names(.) %in% "d" | colSums(!is.na(.)) > 0)

# A tibble: 4 x 6
      a b      c     d        AR    BR   
  <int> <chr>  <chr> <chr>    <chr> <chr>
1     1 animal dog   NA       NA    NA   
2     2 animal cat   NA       NA    NA   
3     3 animal rat   NA       NA    NA   
4     4 plant  oak   carvalho NA    NA
```

Answer (score 3):

We can wrap `select` with `select_if`

```
df %>% 
   filter(b == 'animal') %>% 
   select(select_if(., ~ any(is.na(.))) %>% names %>% setdiff('d'), setdiff(names(.), 'd'))
```

Or as inspired from @H1 comments

```
library(purrr)
df %>% 
  filter(b == 'animal') %>%
  select_if(names(.) != 'd'| summarise_all(., ~ any(!is.na(.))) %>% flatten_lgl)
```

Comment: @RubemDornas Any chance you loaded `select` from another package that masked the `dplyr::select`

Comment: @RubemDornas May be it is the package version as I am using the devel version of `dplyr`.  Let me test on CRAN version

Comment: Great, @akrun, the last one seems to work properly. Thank you! Should we remove the previous not working answers and comments in order to avoid confusion by others or is it better to keep them? First time making a question, I don't know exactly how it works.